# Manipulate a URL with a spinner

Tags: java, android

I want to choose an item out of the spinner. And then it should open an URL in the Webview which only changes one number in the base URL. How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea.

You implement an `OnItemSelectedListener` by extending it. Inside of this listeners `onItemSelected()` method you just manipulate your string appropriately and start your other activity.

Here is an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html) on how to work with a `Spinner`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from the Spinner with

```
getSelectedItem.toString()
```

Build your url with

```
String.format()
```

And update your webview with

```
WebView.loadUrl()
```